# How do clojure multimethods use namespaces?

Tags: clojure

I declare a multmethod with defmulti but then I have defmethods scattered all around my code base and it seems to "just work" without having to declare any explicit namespace in front of the multimethod declaration! Is this because all multimethods use some form of global namespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to repeat the multimethod's namespace in front of the multimethod's name because you have already referred the multimethod's name in your namespace, probably via the use of :use in the namespace decl.